# Weird error in cquery using coc.vim on neovim

Tags: c++, vim, language-server-protocol

I have built and installed cquery as explained in it's repository.
But it seems to me that something goes wrong.

This simple code snippet compiles well without any error while cquery shows me an error telling  **invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'const char**

I made lots of researches to configure **.cquery** file and it's paths but I still have no success.

Can anyone please give me a hint on it?
[image: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const char]

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea, however I have a very unrelated question, which font do you use? I quite like it!

Comment: @padawin I use **Operator** font which I patched to support some nerd-icons.